# Bold Symbol in Glossary but not in text

Tags: symbols

I have a file with two types of glossaries and want the symbols to be bold within the glossary (which they are as currently in the code) but when I use them with \gls{xx) in the text or a table, I do not want them to appear bold.
I hope someone can help me with this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks]{acronym}

\usepackage[footskip=2cm, hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]    {geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}                   %enable     onehalfspacing
    \onehalfspacing         
\usepackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}     %hyperlinks are hidden,     hyperref draufklicken und zum punkt im report 
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier} %integration matlab     files, required for glossary
\usepackage{multicol}                               %enable multicolumn
\usepackage[acronym, nonumberlist, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\renewcommand{\glsclearpage}{}

\setglossarysection{section}
\newglossary*{symbols}{List of Symbols}
\makenoidxglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields

\newacronym{pvt}{PVT}{Pressure Volume Temperature}
\newglossaryentry{ng}{type=symbols,name=$\boldsymbol n\raisebox{-.4ex}{\tiny G}$,sort=ng,description={Degree at k\raisebox{-.4ex}{\tiny{{rG}}}}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\gls{pvt} and \gls{ng}


\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
%\twocolumn
\singlespacing
\chapter*{Nomenclature}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printnoidxglossaries
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Good first question, it is very helpful that you have included an MWE (Minimal Working Example) with your code that I could use for my answer. Maybe for your next question you can try to make the MWE even more minimal? There were a lot of packages and other code that was not necessary for reproducing the issue, they could be removed as well.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you very much, your answer helped a lot! Will try to minimize it as much as possible next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to define the format of a glossary entry in the main text using the command `\defglsentryfmt`. This command has an optional argument for the glossary type, so you can define it only for terms of type `symbols`.

The idea is to use this command to switch off `\boldsymbol` in the main text. One way to do that is to store the original definition of `\boldsymbol` to another macro (for example `\origboldsym`), then temporarily redefine `\boldsymbol` to mean nothing (i.e., `\relax`), print the glossary entry, and restore the original definition. Redefining the entry format only affects the main text, so in the List of Symbols the original definition of `\boldsymbol` is used.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[acronym, nonumberlist, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\setglossarysection{section}
\newglossary*{symbols}{List of Symbols}
\makenoidxglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields
\defglsentryfmt[symbols]{%
\let\origboldsym\boldsymbol%
\let\boldsymbol\relax%
\glsgenentryfmt%
\let\boldsymbol\origboldsym%
}
\newacronym{pvt}{PVT}{Pressure Volume Temperature}
\newglossaryentry{ng}{type=symbols,name=$\boldsymbol n\raisebox{-.4ex}{\tiny G}$,sort=ng,description={Degree at k\raisebox{-.4ex}{\tiny{{rG}}}}}

\begin{document}
\gls{pvt} and \gls{ng}

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]